# Listening packets on specific IP and port

Tags: c#, sockets, proxy, tcplistener

I want to listen outcoming packets from someone's application and send forged packets or my own (the same like listened before). I know the destination IP adress and port. I read a lot on that topic and I have a few questions.

1. Can I just create a [`TcpListener`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener(v=vs.110).aspx) and listen to all packets on the exact port and IP address? But I don't want to stop the base program.
2. Can proxy technology help me in this situation?

Comment: You can create a tcplistener to listen and use thread so that it won't stop your base program.

Comment: 1. yes. 2. yes.

Comment: I improved some highlighting and some spelling. The question should be answerable by now. It should have been now indicated by one's of its comments.